# Apigee Java Call Out Response

Tags: ntlm, apigee

In a standalone java code, using Apache `HTTPClient` libs, implementing the **NTLM** Authentication with **SharePoint** Server and accessing its Web Service and receiving the huge XML content as response. Now this final output is in String format. Created the **Java Call Out Policy** and uploaded all the jars.
I need some help here,

How to pass the java's final output response to **Apigee**'s response.

My requirement is: If I hit the **Apigee** API Proxy then I need to receive the Java's output(String) as Apigee's response.

Which policy is more appropriate to handle this response.

Appreciate your help! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `javacallout policy` to author custom java code. Here is a related post in SO: [Working With JAVA Callout in apigee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912998/working-with-java-callout-in-apigee)

You can try 
`message.setContent(string)` to create the content, and
`messageContext.setResponseMessage(Message)`
in java code to directly write to output.